# Modify VBA Checkbox Script for Mac Excel Compatibility

Tags: macos, vba, excel, checkbox

I wrote a vba script for once a user clicks a checkbox for a column, that column's data is populated on another hidden spreadsheet. When the user unchecks the box, the data is removed from the relative column on the hidden spreadsheet. My script works in MS Excel 2010, 2013, but is not working on Mac Excel, and the majority of users who will be using this file are on Mac Excel. What can I do to make it compatible for Mac Excel 2011? (Script is below.)

```
Private Sub columnD_Select()
'If Column D is selected...
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 80").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    Sheets("Data To Display").Range("M2:M10000").ClearContents
    Sheets("SF Data 9 Box").Range("D6:D10000").Copy
Destination:=Sheets("Data To Display").Range("M2")
Else
    Sheets("Data To Display").Range("M2:M10000").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

-Kamili

(RESPONSE TO MAT'S MUG - They are form controls, not active x controls. When I click them on my windows machine, the data populates in their respective columns and when I unclick the boxes, the columns content is cleared. However, on my macbook pro, the checkbox form controls do not populate. all of my other vba code executes fine, it's just the checkboxes that it's not recognizing what to do on-click.)

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague. What exact problem are you facing? If your checkboxes are ActiveX controls, I doubt that's supported at all on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get it to work on both Mac Excel 2011 and MS Word. I linked the checkboxes to a cell on a hidden sheet, then assigned the macro directly to each checkbox instead of referencing the checkbox IDs, and did some small cleanup.

```
 Private Sub columnD_Select()
 'If Column D is selected...
 If Sheets("Checkboxes").Range("D4").Value = True Then
  Sheets("SF Data 9 Box").Range("D6:D10000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Data To Display").Range("M2:M9996")
  Sheets("Data To Display".Range("K2:K10000").Calculate
 Else
  Sheets("Data To Display").Range("M2:M10000").ClearContents
 End If
End Sub
```

Thank you to those who tried to help.
-Kamili